# Finding the condition for equation to be true for all n

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let a,b,c,d be any four real numbers. Then $a^n+b^n=c^n+d^n$ holds for any value of n if:

1)$a+b=c+d$
2)$a-b=c-d$
3)$a+b=c+d,a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$
4)$a-b=c-d,a^2-b^2=c^2-d^2$
I tried to solve this using expansion of $x^n+y^n$. But didn't find any answer to this multiple choice question.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You have

$$a+b=c+d $$ then

$$(a+b)^2=(c+d)^2$$

but

$$a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$$

thus
$$ab=cd $$

or $$\frac {a}{c}=\frac{d}{b}=k.$$

$$a^n+b^n=c^n+d^n \implies $$

$$c^n (k^n-1)=b^n (k^n-1)$$

which gives
$k=1,  a=c , b=d $

or
$b=c , a=d $

Comment: Sir this a multiple choice question so you have to select any one of the given option. Which one do you choose?